# c# lambda query to load item in a related table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, lambda, entity-framework-6

### Lambda Query

I am working with with EF6 MVC5 and set up my listing model to include a virtual ICollection of images. I want to query the listings and include an image with each listing title in my view.  I am having trouble writing the lambda query in the controller to send to my view.

### Listing Class

```
public class Listing
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser User;
    [Required]
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }public string Title { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Website { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string LocationAddress1 { get; set; }
    public string LocationAddress2 { get; set; }
    public string LocationCity { get; set; }
    public string LocationState { get; set; }
    public string LocationZip { get; set; }
    public string LocationCountry { get; set; }
    public double Latitude { get; set; }
    public double Longitude { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string Comments { get; set; }
    public bool isLEO { get; set; }
    public bool isProperty { get; set; }
    public string Keywords { get; set; }
    public bool isNoShowAddress { get; set; }
    public bool isActive { get; set; }
    public bool isApproved { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Image> Images { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Review> Reviews { get; set; }
```

### Image Class

```
public class Image
{
    public int Id { get; set; }        
    public Listing Listing { get; set; }
    public int ListingId { get; set; }
    public string ImagePath { get; set; }
    public bool isPrimary { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }
    public bool isHidden { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What have you written so far? Lets see your Linq or Lamda code.

Comment: I do not understand. You have a collection of Images, but you want a single image for each Listing in your query? And which one?

Comment: I will be selecting the one where isPrimary is marked as true.

Comment: var listings = db.Listings.Include(c => c.Images)
                    .Where(c.ListingId == Listings.Id && c.isPrimary == true)
                    .FirstorDefault();

Answer (score 0):

When you have nested objects I believe you do something like this:

```
var listings = dbcontext.Listings.Include("Images").Where(...)
```

Where include tells EF to fetch nested objects.
It could also be something like this:

```
var listings = dbcontext.Listings.Include(c=>c.Images).Where(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to project your query to another type specifically designed for use inside Views (this is often referred to as ViewModel) or you can just project it into an anonymous type, the approach is similar.

The following code assumes you will use an anonymous type:

```
var listings = dbContext.Listings.Select(l => new {
    Id = l.Id,
    User = l.User,
    //add every property you need to show inside your View
    Image = l.Images.FirstOrDefault(i => i.isPrimary)
});
```

Comment: Fantastic!  Thank you.